# How do I peform a Segue with an UITableView while doing a swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to make a navigation between my viewController and EditBrainDump. The only problem is: how do I perform a segue with an UITableView?

**Error**:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f940c526660> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputName.'
```

Code for the action:

```
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
        // share item at indexPath
        let itemId = self.brainList[indexPath.row].id
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editbraind", sender: self)


        print(itemId)
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return [delete, edit]

}
```

Comment: You "linked" an IBOutlet `inputName` in InterfaceBuilder, but you didn't set the class of the `UIViewController` which is by default `UIViewController` instead of your custom viewController, something like `EditBraindViewController` or `EditBrainDump`.

Comment: Thanks you! I fixed it much love, thanks for your time and effort.